# Is there any better way to find the digit multiplication and summation?

Tags: c#, algorithm

```
int N = 2345;
        var digitArray = N.ToString().ToCharArray();
        int multiplicationSum = 1;
        foreach (char digit in digitArray)
        {
            multiplicationSum = int.Parse(digit.ToString()) * multiplicationSum;
        }
        var sum = 0;
        var sumArray = multiplicationSum.ToString().ToCharArray();
        foreach (char digit in sumArray)
        {
            sum = int.Parse(digit.ToString()) + sum;
        }
```

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Assuming you don't need to deal with negative numbers, it seems doing it mathematically would make a lot more sense

```
int N = 2345;
int multiplicationSum = 1;
while(N!=0)
{
  multiplicationSum = multiplicationSum * (N%10);
  N = N/10;
}
var sum = 0;
while(multiplicationSum!=0)
{
  sum = sum + (multiplicationSum%10);
  multiplicationSum = multiplicationSum/10;
}
```

---

References:

[% operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0w4e0fzs.aspx)

> The % operator computes the remainder after dividing its first operand by its second

[/ operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3b1ff23f.aspx):

> When you divide two integers, the result is always an integer. For example, the result of 7 / 3 is 2