# Recursive sum to find single digit

Tags: c#, algorithm

I have a number as N=2345

If I sum them the result will be 2+3+4+5 =14;

If I further sum them it will be 1+4 = 5; which is a single digit;

What is the efficient way to find this?

I am following the answer ([Is there any better way to find the digit multiplication and summation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17080289/is-there-any-better-way-to-find-the-digit-multiplication-and-summation#comment24703634_17080289)) and have written a recusive funciton but does not work

```
public static int FindSingleDigit(int N)
{
        var sum = 0;
        while (N != 0)
        {
            sum = sum + (N % 10);
            N = N / 10;
        }
        if (sum >= 10) FindSingleDigit(sum);
        return sum;
}
```

Comment: Not much different from your [previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17080289/is-there-any-better-way-to-find-the-digit-multiplication-and-summation). Why two questions?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's the [`digital root`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_root) of the number, which is just going to be N%9 or 9 if N%9 is 0:

```
int digitalRoot = 1 + (N-1)%9;
```

So no need for recursion?

Answer (score 3):

```
int a = 123456;
int result = a;

while (result >= 10)
   result = result.ToString()
                  .Sum(x => int.Parse(x.ToString()));
```

Comment: @David: `10` is not single digit

Comment: yep. I shall delete my comment.

Comment: but i need to find out the steps also.. like in pass 1 it is 1+2+3+4+5+6=21. in second pass it is 2+1 = 3.. so there are two passes

Comment: @priyanka.sarkar: you just use one variable to count the `loop`, that's easy

Answer (score 1):

Instead of

```
if (sum >= 10) FindSingleDigit(sum);
    return sum;
```

try

```
if (sum >= 10)
    return FindSingleDigit(sum);
else
    return sum;
```